# Position rotated div

Tags: jquery, css, rotation, jquery-ui-draggable, resizable

I'm trying to rotate and resize elements ('furniture' in my roomplanner).
Every element (image) has a div wrapped. This div is draggable, the image can be rotated. There is a second div wrapped around the image wich I use for resizing.

```
<div class="element furniture" height="53" width="146">
    <div class="imageholder">
        <img width="146" height="53" src="/images/furniture/bankstel_3zits.png" />
    </div>
</div>
```

After rotation I set the height of the div to the width of the image and the width of the div to the height of the image. But, when I rotate, div's are on another position then the image inside.. I tried working with margins but I guess this is not the correct solution?

I've setup an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/Hqcnh/6/

Comment: By default, your image is rotating around its center-point. Why don't you rotate the whole `div` instead of just the image inside?

Comment: Well, at first I rotated the whole div but then I have a problem with resizing.. (the handles wont rotate)

Answer (score 1):

Rotate the parent div, everything else will rotate

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.rotate').click(function () {
       Rotate();

    });
    function Rotate(){
         var clickedElement = $('.element.furniture');
        var imageHolder = clickedElement.find('.imageholder');
        var clickedElementToRotate = $('.element.furniture');

        var degrees = 90;
        if (typeof (clickedElementToRotate.attr('rotate')) !== 'undefined') {
            degrees = parseFloat(clickedElementToRotate.attr('rotate')) + 90;
        }

        clickedElementToRotate.attr('rotate', degrees);
        clickedElementToRotate.cssrotate(degrees);

        if (degrees == 90 || degrees == 270) {
            clickedElementToRotate.attr('data-width', clickedElementToRotate.height()).attr('data-height', clickedElementToRotate.width());
        } else {
            clickedElementToRotate.attr('data-width', clickedElementToRotate.width()).attr('data-height', clickedElementToRotate.height());
        }



    }
    $("div.element.furniture").each(function () {
        var div = $(this);
        var img = $(this).find('img');

        div.draggable();
        div.css('border', '1px solid red');
        div.width(img.width());
        div.height(img.height());

        img.wrap('<div class="imageholder" />');
        div.find('.imageholder').css('border', '1px solid blue').css('width', div.width());
        div.find('.imageholder').css('height', div.height());

        div.find('.imageholder').resizable({
            handles: "n, e, s, w",
            aspectRatio: true,
            resize: function (event, ui) {

                if (img.attr('rotate') == 90 || img.attr('rotate') == 270) {
                    img.css('width', ui.size.height);
                    img.css('height', ui.size.width);
                } else {
                    img.css('width', ui.size.width);
                    img.css('height', ui.size.height);
                }

                div.css('width', ui.size.width);
                div.css('height', ui.size.height);
            }
        });
    });
});


(function ($) {
    var _e = document.createElement("canvas").width;
    $.fn.cssrotate = function (d) {
        return this.css({
            '-moz-transform': 'rotate(' + d + 'deg)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'rotate(' + d + 'deg)',
                '-o-transform': 'rotate(' + d + 'deg)',
                '-ms-transform': 'rotate(' + d + 'deg)'
        }).prop("rotate", _e ? d : null);
    };
    var $_fx_step_default = $.fx.step._default;
    $.fx.step._default = function (fx) {
        if (fx.prop != "rotate") return $_fx_step_default(fx);
        if (typeof fx.elem.rotate == "undefined") fx.start = fx.elem.rotate = 0;
        $(fx.elem).cssrotate(fx.now);
    };
})(jQuery);
```

See this fiddle here [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Hqcnh/7/)

Comment: Thnx, but now I have a problem with resizing.. (the handles wont rotate), that's why I only rotated the image.